node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148 throw err
Muy buenas, al tratar de instalar Angular y Node.js me da un error con respecto al npm, prácticamente como no instalado (Lo compruebo en powershell). Volví a instalar el Node.js y persiste el error. Les agradecería si pueden ayudarme con alguna solución. Muchas gracias.
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Windows\system32> node --version
v20.13.0
PS C:\Windows\system32> npm --version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\lpilc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.13.0



Valida si el npm lo tienes configurado en las Variables de Entorno de tu sistema y si no lo tiene, puede agregarlo de esta forma:

Espero te sirva.

Si esta respuesta te ayudó, por favor márcala como aceptada.


Valida si ambas están en Path:
C:\Program Files\nodejs\ C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm

Si ambas están en Path, instala una version anterior como la v18.20.2. Me funcionó https://nodejs.org/en/download/



mi compañero tenia el mismo error, exactamente igual al tuyo, y el probó con el comando:
npm install -g npm@latest
Instala pero demora bastante, creo que demoro como 6 u 8 minutos en instalar.
Y por suerte le soluciono el problema. Espero que le sirva a alguien esta información. :D

una de las cosas que puedes hacer es :
1.- Elminar la carpeta node_modules.
2.- Eliminar el package-lock.json.
Después , seria bueno que reinicies el vscode.
Al regresar a la terminal deberás colocar :
npm install

Una vez terminada la instalación , deberás seguir con :
npm start

verás que regresará el package-lock.json
Nota: No necesariamente debera ser npm start , esto dependera en como esté en tu package.json , puede ser también npm admin:dev o similar.
Nota 2: También debes tener en cuenta que node.js esté en las variables de entorno.
Otra cosa es que si no te resulta hacerlo con la última version de node.js puedes aliminarla e instalar la version v18.20.2 , versión en la cual solucioné el problema.
Nota 3: Eso me sucedio al usar yarn , puedes solucionar primero el problema con npm y despues pasar a trabajar con yarn.
Espero te ayude , saludos.

Revisen este video, y haganlo tal cual, yo intente con muchos metodos como eliminar la carpeta, con el npm init etc, y ninguno me funciono hasta este video que me encontre, revisenlo, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gP2sRfifEfo, espero les sirva :3

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.

Ve a tus variables de entorno del sistema, busca Path y elimina todas las que son de node y npm.
Luego solo copia C:\Program Files\nodejs o la ruta hasta donde esté realmente instalado tu nodejs
